# Having trouble with a programatically created CustomValidator ServerValidate event for a CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to dynamically create a `CustomValidator` for an asp.net `CheckBoxList` with C#.  I seem to have the creation of the validator down just fine, but the `ServerValidate` is giving me some trouble.  I modeled it after an individual `CustomValidator` that I manually created which is working well, so I'm not quite sure what I need to do differently.

Here is the manual `CustomValidator` that works perfectly.  This was my model:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomV_JobPositions" runat="server" 
     ErrorMessage="Please select at least one job position." 
     OnServerValidate="CustomV_JobPositions_ServerValidate" 
     ValidationGroup="JobPositions" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red">
</asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CBL_JobPositions" runat="server" 
     DataSourceID="JobPositionsEntity" DataTextField="JobPosition1" 
     DataValueField="JobPositionID" RepeatColumns="3" Width="100%" 
     OnSelectedIndexChanged="CBL_JobPositions_SelectedIndexChanged" 
     AutoPostBack="True" ValidationGroup="JobPositions">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and in the codebehind:

```
protected void CustomV_JobPositions_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = false;                              // Assume initially that nothing is checked
    foreach (ListItem item in CBL_JobPositions.Items)  // Loop through each list item in the checkbox
    {
        if (item.Selected == true)                     // If at least one item is checked...
        { args.IsValid = true; }                       // ... then mark the whole list as valid...
    }
}
```

So all of the above works fine.
Then I try to replicate it dynamically/programmatically:

```
public CustomValidator CreateDynamicCustomCheckBoxListValidator(string ControlToValidate, string ValidationGroup)
{

    CustomValidator CV = new CustomValidator();                  // Set up a new CustomValidator
    CV.ID = "CustomV_" + ControlToValidate;                      // Set Validator ID with the name of desired control
    CV.ErrorMessage = "At Least One Selection Required";         // ... then set the error message to "at least one selection required"
    CV.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;                     // Make the validator error display red
    CV.ValidationGroup = ValidationGroup;                        // Assign this validator to a group
    CV.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;                       // Make the validator display dynamically
    CV.ServerValidate += new ServerValidateEventHandler(CustomV_CheckBoxList_ServerValidate);
    return CV;                                                   // Return the completed validator that was just created
}

private void CustomV_CheckBoxList_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = false;                        // Assume initially that nothing is checked
    CheckBoxList CBL = (CheckBoxList)source;
    foreach (ListItem item in CBL.Items)         // Loop through each list item in the checkbox
    {
        if (item.Selected == true)               // If at least one item is checked...
        { args.IsValid = true; }                 // ... then mark the whole list as valid...
    }
}
```

It seems to create the `CustomValidator` with no trouble, but when it comes time to actually do the validation, it throws the following error:

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CustomValidator' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList'."

The only problem with that is I need to loop through the checkbox list, and without that cast, I can't program it to do anything with the source.  For example, the following code gives me this error: "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'object' because 'object' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'"

```
private void CustomV_CheckBoxList_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = false;                       // Assume initially that nothing is checked
    //CheckBoxList CBL = (CheckBoxList)source;
    foreach (ListItem item in source)           // Loop through each list item in the checkbox
    {
        if (item.Selected == true)              // If at least one item is checked...
        { args.IsValid = true; }                // ... then mark the whole list as valid...
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work/what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post but I came across a similar issue for a CheckBox so thought I would post how I got round this problem.

Create an object inheriting from CustomValidator and give it a property called ControlId:

public class CustomValidatorWithValidatedControlAttributes : CustomValidator
    {
        public string ControlId { get; set; }
    }

Dynamically create an instance of the CustomValidatorWithValidatedControlAttributes, providing the ControlId property:

var customValidator = new CustomValidatorWithValidatedControlAttributes
                        {
                            ID = string.Concat(TheControl.ID, "_customFieldValidator"),
                            EnableClientScript = false,
                            Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic,
                            ErrorMessage = "Required",
                            CssClass = "error",
                            ControlId = TheControl.ID
                        };
                        customValidator.ServerValidate += customValidator_ServerValidate;

And then in the ServerValidate method cast the object back to the CustomValidatorWithValidatedControlAttributes class, and from the ControlId property get access to the Checkbox and then check whether it's checked:

```
    void customValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        var customValidator = source as CustomValidatorWithValidatedControlAttributes;
        if (customValidator != null)
        {
            var checkBox = FindControl(customValidator.ControlId) as CheckBox;
            if (checkBox != null)
            {
                args.IsValid = checkBox.Checked;
            }
        }

        args.IsValid = false;
    }
```